# x86 acquire semantics fetch and increment?

Tags: x86, memory-barriers

Suppose I have a timestamp counter.

```
 static uint32_t _Atomic timestamp = 0U;

 static inline uint32_t get_ts(void) {
       return atomic_fetch_add_explicit(&timestamp, 1, memory_order_acquire);
 }
```

Suppose I have some concurrent code and I want to experimentally test and log memory reorderings.

```
 for (;;) {
     uint32_t ts1 = get_ts();
     struct result result_a = do_a();

     uint32_t ts2 = get_ts();
     struct result result_b = do_b();

     log(ts1, &result_a);
     log(ts2, &result_b);
  }
```

Under the c11 memory model `do_a` might possibly be reordered past `get_ts` with `do_b()`.

```
 for (;;) {
     uint32_t ts1 = get_ts();
     uint32_t ts2 = get_ts();
     struct result result_b = do_b();
     struct result result_a = do_a();

     log(ts1, &result_a);
     log(ts2, &result_b);
  }
```

However, assuming the compiler does not reorder things on x86 `lock xadd` acts as a barrier to all loads and stores. So, it is in fact impossible for x86 (but not the compiler) to do this reordering because the `get_ts` call acts as a acquire release fence.

Is there a way on x86 to have a true acquire semantics fetch and increment?

Comment: x86 doesn't even have anything as weak as `std::memory_order_acq_rel`, only `seq_cst` (x86 `lock` prefix) for atomic RMW ops.  You can (and maybe should) still write your code with as weak an ordering as you're *sure* will maintain correctness, especially if you can test it on an ARM or other weakly-ordered system.  But keep in mind that any atomic RMW on x86 always has sequential consistency (not just acq_rel) at the asm level, so if you can take advantage of that, you should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is untrue in the 'lock xadd' implementation of the fetch_add ?

If you mean that you do not want the stronger semantic of the full barrier provided by the locked RWM op, then on x86 you indeed do not have any other choice.  For loads, plain load MOV instruction does provide the 'true' acquire semantic in this sense, since stores executed in program order before the MOV might be observed by other CPUs after it, due to store buffering.

Answer (score 3):

Whether the compiler is allowed to reorder `do_a` and `do_b` depends on what these functions do.
Optimisations on atomics are possible<sup>[[1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html)]</sup>, but subject to section 5.1.2.4 of the C11 standard<sup>[[draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf)]</sup>. (I believe this is the relevant one.)

The site [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order) offers a reworded view on the topic, including a definition of the semantics of `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release`.
A load with acquire semantics and a store with release semantics can be implemented as:

```
Acquire load                       Release store
Load                               #StoreStore
#LoadLoad                          #LoadStore
#LoadStore                         Store
```

Where the # denotes a fence (memory barrier).
However, in the [Intel memory ordering white paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-f10/doc/Intel_Reordering_318147.pdf), it is clearly stated that LoadLoad, StoreStore and LoadStore reordering is *never* performed on temporal loads/stores.
Thus release-acquire semantics come free on x86.

This is not a matter of using a locking (and thus serializing) instruction like `lock xadd`; release-acquire semantics are simply always respected—even with simple `mov` instructions.
Note that the acquire semantics have nothing to do with stores performed *before* the acquiring load; it orders stores and loads *after* it.

As for your last question, it is a bit unclear.

> Is there a way on x86 to have a true acquire semantics fetch and increment?

An implementation that serializes all the instructions *has* acquire semantics. In this regard, x86 doesn't do any reordering.

If you meant, is there a way to have atomic operations that are not sequentially consistent (in the C11 meaning), then the answer is no.
You can find the relevant section in the Intel manuals, but you can also find it in the whitepaper linked above. It says:

> 7. In a multiprocessor system, locked instructions have a total order.
> 8. Loads and stores are not reordered with locked instructions.

By requiring an atomic RMW (read-modify-write) operation, you also enforce a sequential consistent order on the atomic variable.